# Prove that the relation $R = \{(f,g)\in F \times F \mid \exists h \in P:(f = h^{-1}\circ g\circ h)\}$ is reflexive.

Tags: functions, relations

Prove that the relation $R = \{(f,g)\in F \times F \mid \exists h \in P:(f = h^{-1}\circ g\circ h)\}$  is reflexive, where $F = \{ f \mid f : A \to A\}$ and $P = \{f\in F \mid f\text{ is one-to-one and onto} \}$. The original problem was to show that it is an equivalence relation, but the symmetry and transitivity were easy to prove. However, i am stuck proving that this is reflexive, or in other words I cant seem to find that function  $h \in P$ for which for an arbitrary $f \in F,\  f = h^{-1}\circ f\circ h$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The identity function is in $P$.